# Unpack lists with different numbers of tuples into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, unpack

Now I have a Series that groups cases by customer ID.

| Index |  |
| --- | --- |
| (Cust-1,2) | [(Case-11,Open),(Case-12,Closed)] |
| (Cust-2,3) | [(Case-21,Open),(Case-22,Closed),(Case-23,Open)] |

And the expected output will look like this.

| Cust ID | Count | Case ID | Case Status | Case ID | Case Status | Case ID | Case Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cust-1 | 2 | Case-11 | Open | Case-12 | Closed |  |  |
| Cust-2 | 3 | Case-21 | Open | Case-22 | Closed | Case-23 | Open |

Comment: kindly share the source dataframe as a dictionary: ``df.to_dict()``

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#example of dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : ['(Cust-1,2)', '(Cust-2,3)'],
    'col2' : ['[(Case-11,Open),(Case-12,Closed)]',
              '[(Case-21,Open),(Case-22,Closed),
                (Case-23,Open)]']})

a = df['col1'].str.split(",", 2, expand=True).replace(to_replace = "[,(\)\[\]]", 
                                                  value="", regex=True)
b = df['col2'].str.split(",", 5, expand=True).replace(to_replace = "[,(\)\[\]]", 
                                                  value="", regex=True)
cols = ['Cust ID', 'Count', 'Case ID', 'Case Status', 
        'Case ID', 'Case Status', 'Case ID', 'Case Status']
new_df = pd.concat([a,b], axis =1)
new_df.columns = cols
```

*result*

```
  Cust ID Count  Case ID Case Status  Case ID Case Status  Case ID Case Status
0  Cust-1     2  Case-11        Open  Case-12      Closed     None        None
1  Cust-2     3  Case-21        Open  Case-22      Closed  Case-23        Open
```